# explode string only by outer delimter in PHP

Tags: php, tokenize, explode

I have a source from where I get pairs of latitudes and longitudes where they are separated by comma and enclosed in parenthesis, and pairs themselves are also separated by commas.I want to fetch each pair and store in a table

[image]

**Tried:**

```
$str = "(a,b),(c,d),(e,f),(g,h)"; //a,c,e,g = latitudes b,d,f,h = longitudes

$str = explode(',' , $str);

print_r($str);
```

**Desired**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => (a,b)
    [1] => (c,d)
    [2] => (e,f)
    [3] => (g,h)
)
```

**Actual:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => (a
    [1] => b)
    [2] => (c
    [3] => d)
    [4] => (e
    [5] => f)
    [6] => (g
    [7] => h)
)
```

My idea was once I get my desired output I can loop over them and ..

```
$tmp = trim('(a,b)', '()'); //  "a,b"
$res = explode(',', $tmp);  //  ['a','b'] 
/* store $res[0] and $res[1] */
```

So how can I get the desired result or is there any better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe

```
$str = "(a,b),(c,d),(e,f),(g,h)"; //a,c,e,g = latitudes b,d,f,h = longitudes
$str = str_replace('),', ')|', $str);
$str = explode('|',  $str);
print_r($str);

Output:
Array
(
    [0] => (a,b)
    [1] => (c,d)
    [2] => (e,f)
    [3] => (g,h)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you use regular expressions?
I think you could try this:

```
<?php 
// https://regex101.com/r/xiO0jy/2
// with latitude and longitude values
// this is just an example: 
$values = "(1.4,2.4),(3.33,7.89),(-7.123,9.01),(-4.58,-2.32)";

/* 
    The expression: \d*\.\d* is for decimal numbers 
    The expression: \( \) is for the parentheses
    The expression: -{0, 1} is for negative values
    The expression: (?: ) is to group the matches
*/
$regex = '/(?:\(-{0,1}\d*\.\d*,-{0,1}\d*\.\d*\))/';

preg_match_all($regex, $values, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

foreach($matches as $m) {
    echo $m[0] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Looks clean but doesn't work for negative longitudes

Comment: Yeah, I added support for negative values

Answer (score 1):

```php
$str = "(a,b),(c,d),(e,f),(g,h)";
preg_match_all('/\(([^(),]),([^(),])\)/', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => (a,b)
    [1] => (c,d)
    [2] => (e,f)
    [3] => (g,h)
)
```

**Update**

use `/\(((-?)\d*.\d*),((-?)\d*.\d*)\)/` pattern to capture negative or positive latitude and longitude pairs

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
function getCoord2($str,$explode=false){
    if(!is_string($str)) return [];
    $coord=[];
    $start=false;
    $latAndLong='';

    for($i=0,$strlen=strlen($str);$i<$strlen;$i++){
        if($str[$i]=='('){
            $start=true;
        }
        if($start){
            $latAndLong.=$str[$i];
        }
        if($start&&$str[$i]==')'){
            $start=false;
            if($explode){
                $coord[]=array_combine(['latitude','longitude'],array_map('trim',explode(',',trim($latAndLong,'()'))));
            }else{
               $coord[]=$latAndLong;
            }
            $latAndLong='';
        }


    }
    return $coord;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r(getCoord2("(a,b),(c,d),(e,f),(g,h)",true));
```

This code print to screen

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [latitude] => a
            [longitude] => b
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [latitude] => c
            [longitude] => d
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [latitude] => e
            [longitude] => f
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [latitude] => g
            [longitude] => h
        )

)
```

print_r(getCoord2("(a,b),(c,d),(e,f),(g,h)"));

will print

```
Array
(
    [0] => (a,b)
    [1] => (c,d)
    [2] => (e,f)
    [3] => (g,h)
)
```

This function result will not be affected by blank characters and space 
for example 
the string

```
"(a,   b),    (c,
d),(e,f),(g,   h)"
```

will be captured as expected but use a simple explode could produce inappropriate results